# Partial derivatives exist everywhere but nowhere differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a function $f$ on an open set $G\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ , which  $f_x$ and  $f_y$ exist everywhere but $f$ is nowhere differentiable in $G$?

Comment: see http://bfy.tw/IWx8

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that $f$ is continuous then no. In that case $f_x$ and $f_y$ are both in Baire class $1$; hence they are both continuous on a comeager set, so there exists a point where they are both continuous.

Comment: And what if $f$ has some discontinuous points?